# How to create a frequency table of a variable?

Tags: python

I'd like to create a Frequency Table in Python using bins. My data has a 'Population' column.

```
Population
563626
625741
672591
710231
814180
897934
989415
```

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
Population
563626  - 625741
625741  - 672591
710231  - 814180
897934  - 989415 ...
```

and be able to specify how many bins to use. Any advice?
(I've seen something similar to R's `cut()` function.)

Comment: [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.cut.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by using [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
import numpy as np

population = [
    563626, 
    625741,
    672591,
    710231,
    814180,
    897934,
    989415,
]
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a)<
```

The size and location of the bins can be customized by using the `bins` parameter. If you want to return the density instead of the frequency, set the `density` parameter to 1.

I suggest you read the docs, they are pretty thorough.